# GtkMozEmbed module in PyGtk

Tags: gtk, pygtk, centos

I'm working on a soloution that needs the gtkMozembed module for python.

I had installed the `pygtk2 and genome-python-* packages.`

But still i don't have the `gtkmozembed` module. Can any one tell me how can i install this module.?

I'm also searching for some good repositories for CentOS so that I can update the latest packages. All the repositories now I have, do not maintain the updated packages.

I use `CentOs 6.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Before continuing, note that `gtkmozembed` is deprecated, abandoned by the authors and therefore not packaged in CentOS 6 or Ubuntu Oneiric and later:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-May/033229.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.embedding/c_NMcO-N8wo/discussion

Therefore any use of gtkmozembed is temporary. You may wish to consider the following alternatives which are available as RPM packages on CentOS 6:

- pywebkitgtk : Python Bindings for [WebKitGTK+](http://webkitgtk.org/)
- gnome-python2-gtkhtml2 : Python bindings for interacting with [gtkhtml2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GtkHTML)

I managed to download [gnome-python2-extras](http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/SRPMS/gnome-python2-extras-2.14.2-7.el5.src.rpm) from CentOS 5 and build it on CentOS 6 with the following commands:

```
rpm -ivh http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/SRPMS/gnome-python2-extras-2.14.2-7.el5.src.rpm
# edit ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/gnome-python-extras.spec
# comment out the line starting with %patch1
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/gnome-python-extras.spec
```

Comment: i use QtWebkit now, no more gtk stuff.